# else if not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

This is my coding

```
          <?php
                try
                {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM registration");
                    $stmt->errorInfo();
                    $stmt->execute();

                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                       {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['Autoid'] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['Name'] ."</td>";
                        if($_SESSION['sesuname'])
                         {
                            echo "<td>Its You ". $_SESSION['sesuname'] ."</td>";
                         } 
                        else if(!$_SESSION['sesuname'])
                         {
                             echo '<td>Follow</td>';
                         }
                        echo "</tr>";
                       }
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                       'Database Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
                }
            ?>
```

I'm trying to show the Follow option and loggedin username in final `td`. But, this coding always shows the loggedin username in all rows. I don't know where i made mistake?

Comment: You need to compare the session against the select username to define if they are different or not to know what action to take. Also you're not calling `session_start()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your condition should be,

```
if($_SESSION['sesuname'] == $row['Name'])
{
   echo "<td>Its You ". $_SESSION['sesuname'] ."</td>";
} 
else
{
   echo '<td>Follow</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to check each row to see if the name matches the name stored in the session?

So you want `if($_SESSION['sesuname'] == $row['Name'])`? And any condition on the `else` clause is spurious.

Answer (score 3):

For every row you are only testing your session variable; and then printing it.

Answer (score 0):

check with `isset()`

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['sesuname'])&&$_SESSION['sesuname']==$row['Name'])
```